# Middleware class not exist laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am just learning laravel and I am facing one issue. I am trying to work with session but it is not working.

**Middleware**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle() {
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            return view('admin.auth.login');
        }
//        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
ErrorException in Adminlogin.php line 10: Undefined variable: request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `$request` & `$next` in arguments like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            return view('admin.auth.login');
        }
            return $next($request);
    }

}
```

> See more about - [Defining Middlewares in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
```

Also, you can simply use [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session) helper in your case:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    return session()->has('userid') ? $next($request) : view('admin.auth.login');
}
```